# nth-child(odd) Not Working if Elements In-between Children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, zebra-striping

This is driving me crazy. Using the below code, all the `<h3>` elements get colored. If I remove the `<div>` elements after each `<h3>`, however, only the odd `<h3>` elements get colored, as expected.

Why does this not work? Aren't the `<h3>` elements all children of the same `<div>`? Why does adding elements in-between each `<h3>` element break things when the `<h3>` elements are still children of the main `<div>`?

CSS:

```
.sub-heading:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h3 class="sub-heading">Collections and Archives</h3>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
  <h3 class="sub-heading">Controller</h3>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
  <h3 class="sub-heading">Controller</h3>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nth-of-type instead

Comment: Re: _"Why does this not work?"_ It does work. Your selector `.sub-heading:nth-child(odd)` selects all elements which have the class `sub-heading` ***and*** which represent the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th etc. child of their parent. If an element has the class `sub-heading` and is the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc. child of its parent, it will not be selected.